# Polygon to Polyline tabular data transfer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, data-transfer

I am working with a Divisional database. The division is divided by districts and then the district is further sub-divided by its micro units called sub-districts. Its topological relationship was error free and in the table the polygon data were well defined in its sub-district, district and divisional columns. Now I have drawn its road network throughout the division. There are some highway with unique name that covers more than 6-7 sub-district polygon.

Now I want to create a road database that will break the road at the sub-district boundary line and join the polygon data (Sub-district, district and divisional data) to the clipped road with its existing database. I think it is possible but I couldn't find any solution. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/).  This will add the polygon fields/values into the intersect output layer follow these steps:

1. Run Intersect tool on road layer (input layer 1) and polygon layer (input layer 2).
2. For those road features that do not reside in any polygon features run the [Erase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/) to get those road features that did not intersect.
3. Start edit session of the intersect layer and select those features from the result of the Erase tool.
4. Copy and paste selected erase features to intersect layer.

This should give you a new road layer with the polygon Sub-district, district and divisional data.